# Only certain cross origin requests working using npm cors()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm building a website using react(it runs on localhost:3000), that gets its user info from an API I built that runs on localhost:4000. To allow requests between the two I was told to use the npm cors package to allow cross-origin requests back and forth. I have set up cors in my API as follows: 
`app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}));`

In my react app I have been using axios in order to send get and post requests, I have one such get request in a component that does receive a response:

```
isLoggedIn(){
        let isLogged = false;
        Fetch("http://localhost:4000/IsLogged")
        .then((results)=> {
            console.log(results)
            isLogged = results.data
        })
        .catch((err)   => console.log(err))
        this.setState({loggedIn: isLogged})
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.isLoggedIn();
    }
```

However, When I try receive the user details using this code:

```
getUserDetails(){
    Fetch("http://localhost:4000/userDetails")
        .then((results)=> {console.log(results)})
        .catch((err)   => console.log(err))
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUserDetails()
  }
```

I get this response in the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/login' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4000/userDetails') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is the server side code:

```
app.get("/userDetails",(req,res)=>{
  //if there is no userID associated with the session then the user hasnt logged in, redirect to login
  console.log(req.session.UserID)
  if(!req.session.UserID) {
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login")
  }else{
    let userID = req.session.UserID
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id =" + userID)
    .then((rows) => res.send(rows[0]))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  }
})
```

It's probably something stupid, so I apologize if this is really basic, any reading links on this also would be great. Thanks for any help given!

Comment: Why does the error message say, _“at `http://localhost:3000/login` (redirected from `http://localhost:4000/userDetails`)”_ - what business would your API running on port 4000 have redirecting to the frontend on port 3000 to begin with …?

Comment: It's just checking to see if you're trying to access the user dashboard without having logged in if you type `localhost:4000/userDetails` if you haven't, redirect to the login page

Comment: You said this was an API, why would anyone try to access a user dashboard by calling an API URL? If any of your `:4000` URLs get called without the proper credentials, your API should deal with that by issuing an appropriate error code, not by redirecting to the _frontend_! You are mixing two different things here in a way that makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not `CORS` thing.

You can not redirect from the back-end. In other words if the user did not logged in your api should return a Not-authorized response. Then at your front end you should route to the login page.

The problem is your are trying to access localhost:3000 (front-end) from the back-end. And the cors is setup for port 4000 or the backend.

```
 console.log(req.session.UserID)
 if(!req.session.UserID) {
     //Your should return unauthorized response then check the response at the front end react axios response.
       res.json({
         status: 401,
         message: "Action Not Allowed",
         name: "AUTHORIZATION_ERROR"
       });
     //res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login")
  }else{ ....


getUserDetails(){
Fetch("http://localhost:4000/userDetails")
    .then((results)=> {
        if(results.data.status == 401) {
              // then change the page.
         }
     })
    .catch((err)   => console.log(err))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your file where you have `app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}));` try to add this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

And then in your routes, pass the next, like this:

```
app.get("/userDetails",(req,res,next)=>{
  //if there is no userID associated with the session then the user hasnt logged in, redirect to login
  console.log(req.session.UserID)
  if(!req.session.UserID) {
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login")
  }else{
    let userID = req.session.UserID
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id =" + userID)
    .then((rows) => res.send(rows[0]))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  }
})
```

Let me know if it worked!
P.S - Which server side handling are you using? Provide so we can help you better!

Comment: no I added all that in and restarted the server and still no luck!

Comment: Which server side handling are you using?

Comment: I'm using Express.js is the package I'm using to handle my HTTP requests

Comment: @MiguelCruz Man, that was not a `cors` issue at all.

Comment: Yes i can see that. You're totally right. I didn't pay attention to the port. he just gotta use the 4000 instead of the 3000. But i'll leave my answer in case anyone have a cors problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below middleware in your node server to modify incoming requests. just place this before your routs and it will do the trick..

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type"
  );
  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

Comment: I tried your snippet too and it didn't work, I appreciate the comments!